# Continuous extension of $\sin(1/x)$ at $0$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was wondering whether the map $\sin(1/x)$ may be continuously extended as follows:

Take $[0,1]$ and "identify" the point $0$ with $[-1,1]$ and then somehow look at the "quotient topology" (I never worked with it and only have intuitive ideas what it does). Now I do not know much about topology I was just wondering as it somehow makes sense to me (visually). I think one way to do it would be to just close the graph $\{(x,\sin(1/x)) \mid x\in (0,1]\}$ and then look at the projection to the first component. That should do about what I try to do, but it is just not the same as I then use the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ I guess.

I don't have much to add to the question and sorry for it being vague. Maybe someone gets what I am trying to say.

**EDIT:** Roughly what I want to do is just say that $sin(\frac{1}{0}) = [-1,1]$ and see the latter as a point in order to make it somewhat continuous. I just don't know how or why (in what setting) this should or should not work.

Comment: I think this is not possible because left and right limits as $x$ approaches zero would have been different even if they existed.

Comment: Easier: take $\;\Bbb R\; $ with the discrete topology... Then **any** function on it to any other topological space is continuous.

Comment: I do not see what you mean as we only restrict to $[0,1]$? And why would they be different in the first place when taking the whole interval to be zero?

Comment: @DonAntonio that is true, but I really want to know whether this exact construction works.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are thinking of the following property: $f$ is continuous implies that the graph of $f$ closed. However, the way that you are closing the graph does not give a graph.

Taking the quotient topology would make the graph closed (I think), but then it's no longer the graph of a function, let alone a continuous function: the graph of a function from $X$ to $Y$ is in $X\times Y$, not any quotient of it.

Closing the graph $\{(x,\sin(\frac1x))\mid x\in(0,1]\}$ gives a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, but it is not a graph of a function either because it contains $\{0\}\times[0,1]$, so it does not satisfy the unicity of the image.

**Edit:** Responding to your edit, you could consider the functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, with the appropriate topology on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. I remember seeing some sort of discussion on this MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179123/continuous-relations.

Comment: Yes but I do not want continuous extension in the usual sense with unicity. I edited the post maybe this helps with the question.

Comment: Is not true that $f$ is continuos iff the graph is closed. What it's true is that $f$ is continuos implies that the graph is closed. For a counterexample for the reciprocal, take $f$ defined over $(-\infty,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = 1/x$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f = 0$ if $x = 0$, . The graph of $f$ is clearly closed, however $f$ is not continous at $0$.

Comment: thank you @HFKy, I'll edit my post.

Comment: and @0CT0, I added a response to your edit.